# Adding HTML to my RSS/Atom feed in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rss, builder, atom-feed

The default rails XML builder escapes all HTML, so something like:

```ruby
atom_feed do |feed|  
  @stories.each do |story|  
    feed.entry story do |entry|   
      entry.title story.title
      entry.content "<b>foo</b>"
    end  
  end  
end
```

will produce the text:

```html
<b>foo</b>
```

instead of: **foo**

Is there any way to instruct the XML builder to not escape the XML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

turns out you need to do

```
entry.content "<b>foo</b>", :type => "html"
```

althought wrapping it in a CDATA stops it working.

Answer (score 9):

```
entry.content "type" => "html" do
    entry.cdata!(post.content)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

http://builder.rubyforge.org/classes/Builder/XmlMarkup.html

> The special XML characters <, >, and & are converted to <, > and & automatically. Use the << operation to insert text without modification.